# jquery の ajax 通信で json データを複数同時に取得したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

jqueryのajax通信にてjsonデータを複数同時に取得する関数を作成したいと考えております

URLとパラメータの連想配列を配列`request`に格納し、
格納されている分だけ`getDataMultipul`メソッドにて実行
全て取得した後に、処理を続行させる形の作りを検討しているのですが、

`when`で並列実行する方法と
その結果を一度に取得し、配列に格納する方法が思いつかずやなんでおります。

何かいい方法ご存知でしたらご教授いただけませんでしょうか?

宜しくお願いいたします。

```js
var request = [
  {"url":"URLその1","params":{パラメータ1}},
  {"url":"URLその2","params":{パラメータ2}},
  {"url":"URLその3","params":{パラメータ3}},
  ・・・
]

getDataMultipul(request).done(
  function(data){
    //成功時の処理
  }
).faile(function(){
  //失敗時の処理 
});


function getJson(request,params){
  var defer = $.Deferred();

  $.ajax({
    url         : request,
    type        : 'POST',
    data        : JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType    : 'json',
    success     : defer.resolve,
    error       : defer.reject,
    timeout     : TIMEOUT
   });

   return defer.promise();
}


function getDataMultipul(arr){
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  $.when(
    //配列に入っているURLとパラメータでデータを取得
    getJson(arr[0]["url"],arr[0]["params"]),
    getJson(arr[1]["url"],arr[1]["params"]),
    getJson(arr[2]["url"],arr[2]["params"]),
    …
  ).done(function(ret1,re2,re3・・・){
    //配列分全ての処理が完了したらresolve
    var returns = [
      ret1,
      ret2,
      ret3,
      …
    ]
    defer.resolve(returns);
  }).fail(function(){
    defer.reject() ;
  })
  return defer.promise();
}
```

追記
Jqueryは2系、ECMA5.1にて開発を行っております。

Answer (score 1):

> その結果を一度に取得し、**配列に格納する方法が思いつかず**やなんでおります。

これについてはes6の[rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/rest_parameters)、あるいはES5以下縛りがあれば[arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)が利用できます。

そもそもjQueryのajaxはよっぽど古いバージョンでない限りPromiseを継承したものを（2系まではDeferredを）返すはずなので提示されているコードはなかなかの遠回りをしている気がします。

ネイティブなPromise,またはそのポリフィルとjQuery3.xを使った場合次のようなのでもいけるかと。

```js
const request = [
  {"url":"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/","params":{name: 'hoge'}},
  {"url":"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/","params":{name: 'fuga'}},
  {"url":"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/","params":{name: 'piyo'}},
]

Promise.all(request.map(req=> {
  return $.ajax(req.url, {
    type: 'post',
    data: req.params
  })
})).then(res=> {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

(上記スニペットではES6を使用しています)

---

ES5+jQuery 2.xで試してみました

```js
var request = [
  {"url":"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/","params":{name: 'hoge'}},
  {"url":"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/","params":{name: 'fuga'}},
  {"url":"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/","params":{name: 'piyo'}},
]

// if use promise
Promise.all(request.map(function(req) {
  return $.ajax(req.url, {
    type: 'post',
    data: req.params
  })
})).then(function(res) {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err)
})

// or $.when
$.when.apply($,request.map(function(req) {
  return $.ajax(req.url, {
    type: 'post',
    data: req.params
  })
})).done(function() {
  for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i][0])
  }
}).fail(function(err) {
  console.error(err)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

うーんjQuery.whenちょっと気持ち悪い……

Comment: hinaloe様 ご回答ありがとうございます。jqueryが2系 ES5.1となっておりますので、もしよろしければその場合の記述例もご教授いただけませんでしょうか?また、>そもそもjQueryのajaxはよっぽど古いバージョンでない限りPromiseを継承したものを（2系まではDeferredを）返すはずなので提示されているコードはなかなかの遠回りをしている気がします。 この部分が勉強不足のため理解ができないのですが、何かよい参考等ございましたら合わせて教えていただけますと幸いです。宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 説明はかけていませんがひとまずサンプルだけ追加しました。（ほぼそのままですが）

Comment: hinaloe様 再度のご解説ありがとうございます。おかげさまで、解決いたしました。